# Linux Screen utility does not echo to screen after redirection

Tags: php, bash, shell

I am testing the redirection of running a PHP program into a screen.

Script does this:

```
<?php

for( $i=1; $i<=1000; $i++ )
{
        sleep(1);
        echo $i;
        echo "\n";
}
```

I am running the above with:

```
screen -d -m bash -c 'php forlog.php >> ~/forlog.log 2>&1'
```

Redirection works fine but when I attach to the screen I have no output(blank screen) .

Is there anyway to have the output redirected to both file and within the screen?

P.S: I don't want to use nohup. Also when not redirected, the output can be seen within the screen just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `tee` to append to the log file and write to `STDOUT` (of `screen`) at the same time.

```
screen -d -m bash -c 'php forlog.php 2>&1 | tee -a ~/forlog.log'
```

Comment: Thank you. This does not redirect the stderr when using this.

Comment: This is the one I needed to get the stderr as well: screen -d -m bash -c 'php forlog.php 2>&1 | tee -a ~/forlog.log' . Found it thx to your answer. Upvoting and accepting.

Comment: I have added the missing redirect. Thanks for the comment.